# Pandas (Python) - Problem appending list to empty dataframe with column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I am trying to append a list looking like this

```
myList = ['2018-01-12', 'MMM', 'BUY', 42, 236.5229]
```

to an empty dataframe (with "header" / columns names).

To create the dataframe I've done the following:

```
tradeLog = pd.DataFrame(columns=["DATE", "TICKER", "ORDER_TYPE", "AMOUNT", "PRICE"])
```

I am trying to append the list as a row in the following way:

```
tradeLog.append(myList, ignore_index=True)
```

(NOTICE: My goal i to iterate over some data - a lot of lists in the same format - and the add them one by one to the dataframe)

Comment: `tradeLog.loc[len(tradeLog)] = my_list`

Comment: This works very well - thank you

Answer (score 1):

The pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) reads

> DataFrame.append(other, ignore_index=False, verify_integrity=False, sort=None)
>
> other : DataFrame or Series/dict-like object, or list of these The
>   data to append.

So you need to have to transform your list prior to appending it to your DataFrame:

something that might work is to zip the list of your columns to the content of your  `myList` so it would be:

```
tradeLog = pd.DataFrame(columns=["DATE", "TICKER", "ORDER_TYPE", "AMOUNT", "PRICE"])
myList = ['2018-01-12', 'MMM', 'BUY', 42, 236.5229]
myDict = dict(zip(tradeLog.columns.tolist(), myList))

tradeLog.append(myDict, ignore_index=True)
```

or `tradeLog.append(pd.DataFrame(myDict), ignore_index=True)`

This being said you need to ensure your lists are always the same length as your columns names list.

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.append()` is for appending rows from an other pandas *dataframe or series* (see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)).

So, if it is absolutely necessary to do this line by line, you can

```
tradeLog = tradeLog.append(pd.Series(myList, index=tradeLog.columns), ignore_index=True)
```

(N.b.: `tradeLog.loc[len(tradeLog)] = ...` appends to the end only as long as you have a simple integer index on `tradeLog`, but might break for more complex use cases.)

You might also want to consider this remark from the docs:

> Iteratively appending rows to a DataFrame can be more computationally intensive than a single concatenate. A better solution is to append those rows to a list and then concatenate the list with the original DataFrame all at once.